# FileNotFoundException when importing an xsd

Tags: spring, web-services, xsd, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to create a bean of type DefaultWsdl11Definition, but when the project is deploying to a weblogic environment the schema file location is not being resolved.

Bean:

```
 <bean id="pServiceWsdl" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition">
    <property name="schemaCollection">
        <bean class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaCollection">
            <property name="inline" value="true"/>
            <property name="xsds">
                <list>
                    <value>classpath:/p.xsd</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="targetNamespace" value="http://example.com/p/"/>
    <property name="portTypeName" value="pPortType"/>
    <property name="serviceName" value="pService"/>
    <property name="locationUri" value="/services"/>
</bean>
```

The schema file contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<xsd:include schemaLocation="p1.xsd"/>
<xsd:include schemaLocation="p2.xsd"/>

<xsd:element name="pRequest">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="p" type="C:p"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="pResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="pEnvelope" type="C:pEnvelope"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Error I am receiving is as below:

> Caused By: java.io.FileNotFoundException: d:\p1.xsd (The system cannot find the file specified)

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the complete path in that case.

```
<xsd:include schemaLocation="classpath:com/example/p/oh/incoming/wsdl/com/example/p/xsd/PCBatchEnvelope-1p6.xsd"/>
```

You will also need to use **commons xmlschema** to inline all xsd into single. So to enable that you need to add below dependency in your maven.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.schema</groupId>
     <artifactId>XmlSchema</artifactId>
     <version>1.4.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am still receiving the same error. Do you perhaps have any ideas ?

Comment: ideally it should resolve your issue. check your classpath is pointing to right folder.

Comment: For some reason it keeps searching in for the file in my weblogic domain folder. I tried using a DeafultURIResolver, but no luck so far.